# Alias for verbatim environment

Tags: macros, verbatim

I'm trying to create an alias for the verbatim environment like this:

`\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\begin{verbatim} #1 \end{verbatim}}`

So I can use it like this:

```
 \vb{
      word.
  }
```

But when using it, I get this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.93 \end{verbatim}
```

Where line 93 is the end of a verbatim environment I used after later down the file after closing the `\vb`. If I replace all `verbatim` environments with the `\vb` syntax, then I get this error:

```
Runaway argument?
zip([],B) = case ([],B) of ([],_) => [] | (_,[]) => [] | (x::L,y::R\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
            \par
```

So it seems like the `\vb` is not closing the environment correctly? How do I get this to work ? The end goal is to get a `\vb` command that I can use like I described above, and bonus points if I could indent the stuff in the `\vb` command by a few mm.

Comment: As far as I know, there’s no way in replacing the environment with a command. Nonetheless you should take a deep look into the `fancyvrb`documentation.

Comment: If you just want oneline verbatim text, you could use a `\Verb` variant in Fancyvrb.

Comment: Your statement "So it seems like the `\vb` is not closing the environment correctly" is absolutely correct. Tokens are scanned in search of `\end{verbatim}` and is never found.

Comment: Werner forgot to provide the following link (I found it in another answer of him) from the UK TeX FAQ: [Why doesn’t verbatim work within …?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin).

Comment: Somewhat related: [Verbatim inside a command - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83893/verbatim-inside-a-command?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general rule is that you *can't* have `\begin{verbatim}` or the `\verb` command in the argument to another command, including an argument to `\newcommand`.

If you *really* want to use that syntax, you of course can't have braces in the argument and hope that they will be printed as themselves: either they delimit the argument or they must be printed.

If this limitation satisfies you, then

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vb}{%
  \begingroup
  \advance\@totalleftmargin\parindent
  \@verbatim
  \catcode`{=1 \catcode`}=2 \catcode` =10
  \frenchspacing
  \@vb}
\def\@vb#1{#1\endtrivlist\endgroup} 
\makeatother
```

will allow you to write

```
\vb{
    word.
  }
```

I don't think this is a great improvement than saying

```
\begin{verbatim}
word.
\end{verbatim}
```

If you want a margin indent of the verbatim, look at the option `xleftmargin` in to the `Verbatim` environment provided by the package `fancyvrb`.