# Verbatim inside a command

Tags: verbatim

I have a question about a Verbatim, I want to write a word inside of the subsubsection title. I got an error. How can I fix it?: `\subsubsection{The \verb+@interface+ Section}`

Comment: Use `\protect` before `\verb+@interface+`

Comment: Related: [How to put `\verb` command inside of `\textbf{}` block?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/5764)

Comment: For simple spells like `@interfcae` I'd just write `\subsubsection{The \texttt{@interface} Section}`. When the spells have braces(`{}) in them, just escape them: `\{` or `\}`.

Comment: Thanks to all for your helping. The type of document that I write is a report; I tried with all methods, but the only one that works for me is the `\texttt{}`, although I use the `cprotect`and `fancyvrb` packages.

Comment: (the 2 questions are really exactly identical, not just "related". it's interesting how the (question, top answer) has the exact same number of votes though)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`cprotect` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect):

```
\usepackage{cprotect}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect
...
\cprotect\subsubsection{The \verb+@interface+ Section}
```

However, consider reading through the informative TeX FAQ entry: [Why doesn’t verbatim work within …?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin) In particular, other alternatives like `\texttt{...}` also exist and are far more manageable. Even in your case, using

```
\subsubsection{The \texttt{@interface} Section}
```

works as-is.

Comment: Tip: if the command contains non-letter characters, enclose it inside curly braces, e.g., `\cprotect{\section*}{\verb"@ interface"}`.

Answer (score 15):

The standard `\verb` command cannot be used in the argument of other commands. You can use `\Verb` from the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{The \protect\Verb+@interface+ Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this works, it still doesn't allow for adding special characters in the argument to `\Verb`, so the simpler `\texttt` might be better.

Comment: There's also `\lstinline` which does allow adding special characters, but in an inconvenient syntax. (mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152412/250119 )