# Verbatim Environment in Figure Caption

Tags: packages

verbatim environment is not working in figure caption. Checked [How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block) and [Verbatim inside a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83893/verbatim-inside-a-command) is not working.

```
\documentclass[11pt, double space]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{Sample 1 \cprotect\begin{verbatim} \tau(A) = e^{\chi_0A/(KD_p(K+A))} \end{verbatim} per hour.}
\label{fig:singlecell_chemo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have tried `cprotect` package also. Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `verbatimbox` package.  In this case, you put the verbatim material into a `verbbox` before invoking `figure`, and then recall it with `\theverbbox` inside the figure.

```
\documentclass[11pt, double space]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}\tau(A) = e^{\chi_0A/(KD_p(K+A))} \end{verbbox}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{Sample 1 \theverbbox per hour.}
\label{fig:singlecell_chemo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

p.s. version 3.01 of `verbatimbox` just hit the streets.  It finally has "real" documentation.

Answer (score 9):

You must use `\cprotect` before `\caption`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, double space]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\cprotect\caption{Sample 1 \verb+\tau(A) = e^{\chi_0A/(KD_p(K+A))}+  per hour.}
\label{fig:singlecell_chemo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

BTW: Don't use the environment center inside figure. [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

Comment: Daniel: I have used \cprotect before caption. But  LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. Any ideas?

Comment: @Balakrishnan: Please see: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/516b92597da65fe1772089d5

Answer (score 7):

`\cprotect` needs to be specified *before* `\caption`:

```
\cprotect\caption{Sample 1 \verb|\tau(A) = e^{\chi_0A/(KD_p(K+A))}| per hour.}
```

Then `\cprotect` puts the argument of `\caption` inside a file and uses the
file loading command as safer argument for `\caption`.

Also I have used `\verb` for use of verbatim inside a text line.

Answer (score 4):

Using `\cprotect` or other methods is a good solution for large material.

In case just a control sequence name is needed in a moving argument there's an easier way:

```
\caption{Example of usage of the \texttt{\string\psbox} command}
```

Not documented in the LaTeX manual, but easier than using complex strategies.

If the `\listoffigures` is needed, then a more complex approach is needed:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\captionstring}[1]{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\string\string#1}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{Sample 1 \texttt{\captionstring\psbox}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Moving argument"? `\string` will not survive, when the caption is moved to the `.lof` file.