# LaTeX command inline in the caption of a figure

Tags: floats, captions, verbatim

I want the caption of a figure to contain a LaTeX command without it being executed:

[image]

Using `verbatim` environment doesn't work in this case and throws errors. Please suggest a solution to this.

Comment: some suggestions in [Verbatim Environment in Figure Caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110829/579)

Comment: Use `\texttt{\string\include\string{data/myNewChapterName.tex\string}}`...

Comment: @Werner `\string` will not survive, when the caption is moved to the `.lof` file.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Yes. I meant to add that one should use the optional argument of `\caption[..]{...}` since it seemed appropriate in this case (for such a long caption). That is, not include the lengthy bracketed text as part of the `.lof`-entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A manual solution, which also survives the list of figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  \caption{For example,
    \texttt{\textbackslash include\{data/myNewChapterName.tex\}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]