# string with underscore in \subsection, like ABC_XYZ

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I need in \subsection string with underscore, like ABC_XYZ.

\subsection{Text ABC_XYZ}

When I try to compile with pdflatex:

```
Missing $ inserted ...ine {1.2}Text ABC_XYZ}{4}{subsection.1.1.2}
Extra }, or forgotten $ ...ine {1.2}Text ABC_XYZ}{4}{subsection.1.1.2}
```

I cannot write `ABC\_XYZ`. It is important for me to find this string ABC_XYZ automaticly. And I need this string in table of contents.

Option

```
\verb+ABC\_XYZ+
```

dont work.

Can you help me?

Comment: Use `\_` as in `\subsection{ABC\_XYZ}`  or `ABC\textunderscore XYZ`

Comment: @Harish, I cannot use `\_`, I need `ABC_XYZ` in source text.

Comment: Why you want that in source? Can you please elaborate your use case?

Comment: Do you want to write `xyz` as the subscript of `ABC` in real pdf?

Comment: No, I need "normal" XYZ, not subscript.

Comment: Then why do you need `ABC_XYZ` in the source file? Please elaborate.

Comment: It is important for me to find this string `ABC_XYZ` automaticly. And I need this string in table of contents.

Comment: `underscore` package, perhaps?

Comment: @JosephWright, thank you. I will try without additionals packages, but when it is necessary, I use new package

Comment: Your issues are in no way related to the fact that "ABC_XYZ" occurs in the header of a subsection. They will arise every bit as much in ordinary running text.

Comment: @Mico, yes. But in ordinary running text I use `\verb+ABC_XYZ+`. In `\subsection` I cannot use `\verb`.

Comment: @Ama Then, as you said, your problem is using `\verb` inside a `\section`. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83893/verbatim-inside-a-command might help. By the way, you always can `\texttt{ABC\_XYZ}`.

Comment: I don't think that the posting "Verbatim inside a command" provides good answers to this posting. Importantly, the OP has said nothing about the strings that contain `_` having to be typeset in typewriter/monospaced font -- which is what the various `verbatim` environments almost invariably do.

Comment: @Mico But OP said that “*But in ordinary running text I use `\verb+ABC_XYZ+`. In `\subsection` I cannot use `\verb`*”, which, at least to me, seems to ask for a monospaced/typewriter font.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that if you have underscore characters, you might also have other characters -- such as `%`, `&`, `#`, and `$` -- that have a special meaning in TeX. If so, you may want to use the `url` package and create a command `\purl` (short for "protected url") so that the strings in question can be parts of "moving arguments" (e.g., when they figure in the argument of a `\caption` command):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same} % omit this command if you want monospaced-font look
\newcommand\purl[1]{\protect\url{#1}} % "protected url"
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{Text \purl{ABC_XYZ}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot really imagine the situation that requires you to be able to write `_` in the title of a section, but of course, sometimes you are faced with obscure problems like that.  One way of doing it is to replace

```
\subsection{Text ABC_XYZ}
```

by

```
\catcode`\_=13 
\def_{\textunderscore}
\subsection{Text ABC_XYZ}
\catcode`_=8
```

I will not swear that it does not have unwanted consequences, but it might be actually be the case, since it seems likely that the definition of `\subsection` does not use `_`.

Comment: I use _ frequently in section titles. To cite an example: installation guides. Script names may appear in titles and usually contain underscores.