# How to use \verb|...| in the main \title of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I know that to use `\verb|...|` in a `beamer` presentation you have to add the `fragile` option to the `frame` environment.

But if I use `\verb|...|` in the main `\title` of `\titlepage` it gives me the error:

```
Runaway argument?
guide to \relax \hbox {}#I\catcode `\ \active \<let>-command \csname\endcsname 
! Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@@ProtectSpacesFi was complete.
<to be read again> 
 \par 
l.5 \begin{document}
```

How can I solve it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{Quack guide to \verb|\usepackage{tikzducks}|}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \titlepage
    Why this doesn't work\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \dots whereas this \verb|\usepackage{tikzducks}| works?
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `Quack guide to \texttt{\string\usepackage\string{tikzducks\string}}`, perhaps

Comment: @egreg Joseph Wright was quicker than you, both his first solution and yours work :)

Comment: @egreg ...also his second one, only an `\end{document}` was missing :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Verbatim inside a command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83893/5764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with any other case: you can't use `\verb` in the argument to `\title`. There's always a way of writing the text of a `\verb` out 'in full', here using `\{`, `\}` and `\textbackslash`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{Quack guide to \texttt{\textbackslash usepackage\{tikzducks\}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \titlepage
    Why this doesn't work\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \dots whereas this \verb|\usepackage{tikzducks}| works?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

One could also use the [`cprotect` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect) as described in [How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block), which would give

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\cprotect\title{Quack guide to \verb|\usepackage{tikzducks}|}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \titlepage
    Why this doesn't work\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
    \dots whereas this \verb|\usepackage{tikzducks}| works?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your second solution gives an error...

Comment: @CarLaTeX I've just run that code exactly as given with the current release of `beamer`: it should work fine

Comment: ... but if I use @egreg's solution (given in a comment) can I accept this answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX You can ask him to post a separate answer, though it's much the same as my first suggestion (there are various ways to input non-verbatim versions of what you want).

Comment: Eventually, thinking of it better, I've accepted your answer because the solution with `\cprotect` is more generalized.

Comment: It seems that it can't work on frametitle