# Can I use verbatim macro in \section?

Tags: verbatim

This is the code that fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\catcode`\|\active
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}
\catcode`\| 12 %
\begin{document}
\section{Hello, |world|!}
\end{document}
```

Is it at all possible to fix it, having in mind that `ltxdoc` also fails with similar code (but with a different error message):

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello, |world|!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: no, you can not use verbatim in the argument of any macro, but why do you need verbatim for `world` ?

Comment: Sometimes it may look nice, for example when you describe a technical term in a not-so-technical document: `\section{How you can use |printf()| in C++}`

Comment: why do you need verbatim for `printf()` you can make `|` work here but only for arguments that do not need verbatim at all

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Verbatim inside a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83893/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\catcode`\|\active
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\|\active\protected\def|{\foo|}}
\catcode`\| 12 %
\begin{document}
\section{Hello, |world|!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: like the last question, this is adding literally a single token. I'm not sure writing code at a rate of one question per token is a useful way to proceed.

Comment: On the other hand, this shows how difficult it is to write *bullet-proof* code and to *understand/fix* other people's code when it doesn't work as expected. Unless OP wants to learn how TeX works (most users understandably don't want to), they will be stuck with having to ask a new question every time something goes wrong.