# Compilation fails with "! Missing \endcsname inserted."

Tags: macros, listings, compiling

Hi I've got a strange problem. I've defined a new command to print Linux commands line in the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\shellcmd}[1]
{
  \begin{lstlisting}
    {#1}
  \end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{document}
\shellcmd{gdb \textit{program core}}
\end{document}
```

If I don't use my own defined command but use `\begin...\end` then it compiles. If I however use the command then I get:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.11 \shellcmd{gdb \textit{program core}}
```

Not sure how to resolve this. I haven't seen a similar problem online.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can't put a `listings` environment in the argument to another command. Have a look at the `\lstinline` command of the same package.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the most basic input. For example \lstinline{gdb \texttt{program}} doesn't work.

Comment: The purpose of `\lstinline` is to typeset an "enhanced verbatim", so formatting instructions like `\texttt` don't make much sense inside it.

Comment: What you're trying to do does not and cannot work. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX [is not known](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14739/575) for its transparent error messages, so this one has nothing to do with the actual problem.  In fact, the issue is that the `lstlisting` environment is a form of "verbatim" text, which requires special care in being used as input.  This is the subject of [at least one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72983/575) previous question (actually, I found several; this one seemed similar to yours), and the reason is that such an environment needs its contents to be "pristine" and not previously scanned by TeX.  As egreg suggests in his comment, you should use `\lstinline` instead; however, that too cannot be buried in another macro, for the same reason.  Use it directly instead of `\shellcmd`.

Comment: OK. It doesn't work with minted either. \lstinline seems to only accept the most basic input. I think I'll just preprocess my latex file with a preprocessor first...

Comment: You should read the `listings` manual. You can customize the keywords and their style.